# How to override the inner contact template?

Tags: theming, emails

All I can seem to find is `page--contact.tpl.php`, which allows you to modify the overall layout. But inside this template it just calls

```
print render($page['content']);
```

For nodes, `$page['content']` could be overwritten in `node.tpl.php` but I don't see any sort of template files inside the contact module folder, or anything else to adjust the **inner** layout.

Comment: In the case of $node one would use print render($content); to print everything, and print render($content['body']); to print only the body. You might pull of the same trick here. You'll find the fields with print_r($page['content']);

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to change, but the `contact` path/page is generated via a form (see  contact_site_form() in contact.pages.inc.)